# modx is only showing html code, not the template

Tags: templates, modx

I have installed ModX and Downloaded the "Basic" Template in the Extensionmanager! I chose the Basic Template at my first Page for the Resource! I cant find a Globalsetting to choose an Template? My problem is that if iam going to the site i only get the pure html code shown, no website! Why is this?

Comment: What do you mean it is 'only showing html code?' You are seeing markup in your browser when you load the front end? Can you post an example rather than being so vague. Also - have you looked at the docs at all: http://rtfm.modx.com/display/revolution20/Making+Sites+with+MODx

Comment: As mentioned specific examples would help, are you using Evo or Revo versions of modx? What html code are you getting? etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK there is no "Globalsetting" to choose a template. One of the nice things with MODX is that each resource can specify which template to use. So you can mix and match as required.

Answer (score 0):

You could check if you have set the base href tag in head like this:

```
<base href="http://www.yoursite.com"/>
```

It will tell the site where to start looking for the other files that you have included in your markup.